# D3 bind click event to all text elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm want to bind a click function to all text elements inside a legend from a graph. We have multiple text elements in some legend because in some name we need to superscript. The click work but only on the first text element. The rest of the clicks don't work.

This is what a legend item looks like:

```
<g transform="translate(0,20)">
  <rect x="10" width="50" height="10" stroke="#DD5736" stroke-idth="1" fill="url(#pattern_2)" fill-opacity="0.75"></rect>
  <text x="223.203125" y="8.5" font-color="black" text-anchor="start" lass="legend-text" style="text-anchor: start;">]</text>
  <text x="198.71875" y="8.5" font-color="black" text-anchor="start" class="legend-text" style="text-anchor: start;"> site</text>
  <text x="215.71875" y="5.199999999999999" font-color="black" text-anchor="start" class="legend-text" style="font-size: 7.5px; text-anchor: start;">-1</text>
  <text x="65" y="8.5" font-color="black" text-anchor="start" class="legend-text" style="text-anchor: start;">Triplet radiative decay rate[s</text>
  <text x="191.234375" y="5.199999999999999" font-color="black" text-anchor="start" class="legend-text" style="font-size: 7.5px; text-anchor: start;">-1</text>
</g>
```

This the how the text gets added to the legend

```
legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", 65)
  .attr("y", 8.5)
  .attr("font-color", "black")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr("class", "legend-text")
  .text(function(d) { return d; })
  .on("click", function(d) {
     var yColumnIndex = headers.indexOf(d);
     var visible = this.visible ? false : true;
     var newLegendOpacity = visible ? 0.2 : 1;
     var newChartOpacity = visible ? 0 : 1;
     var chart = "#area_" + headers[yColumnIndex].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "_").replace(/\s/g, "");

     var legendStroke = $(this).parent().find("rect");
     svg.select(chart).style("opacity", newChartOpacity);
     svg.selectAll(".pointClass" + yColumnIndex).style("opacity", newChartOpacity);
     d3.select(this).style("opacity", newLegendOpacity);
     $(legendStroke).css("opacity", newLegendOpacity);

     this.visible = visible;
   });
```

What I've tried is adding a class and then added a click event to that.

```
var text = legend.selectAll(".legend-text");
text.on("click", function(d) { console.log("Hit!") });
```

That didn't resolve the problem. I keep getting the same result that only the first text element is bound to a click event. The superscript is handled by a different function that splits up the text element. Could it be that's the issue?

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced. The click event works for all texts. Therefore, please post a [MCVE] which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, thanks for your reply. I've done a bit more research on my last remark that the superscript is handled by a different function after the legend is added. When I add the click event it works as expected.